# assigning properties of one object to another

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

is it possible to easily and quickly "assigning properties of one object to another"

```
class a {
    public $number_one;
    public $number_two;
    public $number_three;

    function __contruct() {
        //do stuff
    }
}

class b {
    public $my_var;

    function __contruct() {

        $instanc_a = new a();
        extract( $instance ); // but make these extracted object properties of class b????
                              // how? :-(
        echo $this->number_one;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to copy the public (only) properties of `class a` to the current object:

```
class b {
    public $my_var;

    function __construct() {
        $instanc_a = new a();
        $vars = get_object_vars($instanc_a);
        foreach($vars as $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        }

        echo $this->number_one;
    }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/ybgY1)**.

**Note:** You have a typo in your code (two cases of "contruct" instead of "construct") which will prevent things from working as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you actually want `class b` to extend `class a`

```
class b extends a {
    public $my_var;

    function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
        // Now $this refers to anything in class b, or if it doesn't exist here, looks to class a for it

        echo $this->number_one;
    }
}
```